Can we assume/deduce sensor's cut-off frequency from datasheet?
In most of the datasheet I have seen, the cut-off frequency is not explicitly given and the exact type of filter neither. However, most of the time, we have informations about the sampling rate that is achievable, conversion time, oversampling rate.
For instance, for this sensor. The manufacturer gives a maximum "measurement rate" of 2kHz, but which actually depends on additional parameters such as oversampling rate (OSR), averaging filter (DIGFILT), that impacts the final "conversion time per measurement" (see §18.4). It is also specified that extra RC filter can be applied to the communication lines in some cases.
But from my understanding this as nothing to do with the cut-off frequency.
Can we assume anything about the cut-off frequency ?
Is the maximum sampling rate the only information available here ?

All we can say is that "conversion time" lies from 163 us to ~35 ms (magnetic conversion time), depending of the filters used. Note that there is an 'interval time" of 1260 ms (?).

I would say the simple answer is no you can't know for sure.
In this case, the manufacturer provides the information, that you can measure 2khz signals, meaning the IC does not allow you to measure higher frequency signals. They are also using decimation or downsampling, without more information I would say, that they decimate the signal depending on the sampling frequency in order to achieve the smooth 2kHz signal.
But as I already said, no way to know in this case.
